# copying portions of string, which are stored in a char array, to another array

Tags: c, arrays, string, copy, char

I wanted to try and copy parts of strings which are already stored in one array of strings to another empty array. (I think called array of pointers to char arrays )

I would like to copy the first 3 characters of each string and store them in the second array and then print them out - like so

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

Here is my code.

```
void main()
{

/*ARRAY 1*/
char *line1 = "AAAAA";
char *line2 = "BBBBB";
char *line3 = "CCCCC";
char *line4 = "DDDDD";
char *line5 = "EEEEE";
char *line6 = "FFFFF";


char *array1[6];

array1[0] = line1;
array1[1] = line2;
array1[2] = line3;
array1[3] = line4;
array1[4] = line5;
array1[5] = line6;


int i;  

char *array_main[6];

for(i = 0; i<6 ; i++ ) {
    array_main[i] = ("%*.*s\n",1,3,array1[i]);
    printf("%s", array_main[i]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

do i need to do a malloc here ? (for array_main[i]) from what i understand, I am basically just copying the address of the particular characters to array_main's elements.

EDIT - Sorry, I should have made this clearer, I want to collect the strings in array_main and then print them in order outside of the loop which actually copies the data.

Comment: `array_main[i] = ("%*.*s\n",1,3,array1[i]);` this does not do what you think it does - you will need to look at using `sprintf` - and yes, you will need to use `malloc`.

Comment: Ok .. i dont really want to print the array right after allocating a string ... I should have made this clearer, I want to collect the strings in array_main and then print them in order outside of the loop which actually copies the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying pointers to statically declared strings to an array. That's theoretically fine. Howevery, you want to cut off the remainder of the strings, so you need to prepare memory for the target strings, because if you write to the strings you will invoke undefined behaviour.

This line:

```
array_main[i] = ("%*.*s\n",1,3,array1[i]);
```

definitely doesn't do what you want though. I think this shouldn't even compile.

You loop over the array and `malloc` the appropriate size of bytes (3+1), then copy over the parts of the string that you want (don't forget the 0-byte at the end).

So it should look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    array_main[i] = malloc(4);
    snprintf(array_main[i], 4, "%.3s", array[i]);
    printf("%s\n", array_main[i]);
    free(array_main[i]);
}
```

A simpler version (with unneccessary memeory overhead) would be this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    array_main[i] = strdup(array[i]);
    array_main[i][3] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", array_main[i]);
    free(array_main[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can vary the size of the string segment to copy ? also could you explain in    snprintf(array_main[i], 4, "%.3s", array[i]);    what does ,4, and "%.3s"  actually do ?

Comment: man snprintf helps... 4 is the size of the buffer, ".3" limites the ooutput to 3 chars. Well, it's not strictly neccessary here, I just adopted it, because you were using this pattern. And yes you can make the size differ by using "*" instead of hardcoded ' 3'. A bit of reading the man page and experimenting with such a simple program is not to much IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    const char *array1[6] = {"AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFF" };
    char array_main[6][4] = {{0}};//4 : 3 + 1 (+1 for End of string('\0'))
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<6 ; i++ ) {
        strncpy(array_main[i], array1[i], 3);
        printf("%s\n", array_main[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```